# Scala - get Class for a specialized class

Tags: scala, kryo

I need to get a Class object for a specialized class. e.g.

```
import breeze.linalg.DenseVector

val compileTimeClass = classOf[DenseVector[Double]]
println(compileTimeClass)

val denseVector = DenseVector(0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5)
println(denseVector.getClass)
```

Output is:

```
class breeze.linalg.DenseVector
class breeze.linalg.DenseVector$mcD$sp
```

If I understand it correctly, Scala is creating specialized versions of DenseVector at runtime? This is an issue for me as I need to register one of these specialized classes for serialization with Kryo.

Other than calling getClass on a specialized instance of DenseVector, is there not a way to get a Class object of a specialized type?

Comment: Can you modify `DenseVector`?

Comment: Nope. DenseVector is in the Breeze library used by Spark ML. I don't even construct it myslef, the ML API does it for me.

Comment: Well... I think you just need to register `DenseVector` with `kryo`. It should be able to deal with any `DenseVector[A]`, as long as that `A` is also registered with `kryo.`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that even though:

```
kryo.register(classOf[breeze.linalg.DenseVector$mcD$sp])
```

Shows as a compile time error in IntelliJ, it actually compiles and works as expected. It means we'll have to explicitly register every specialization that we use and serialize.
The Twitter chill library gets round this for Tuple* classes by auto generating the registration and serialization code with https://github.com/twitter/chill/blob/develop/scripts/tuple_serializers.scala

Answer (score 0):

Well... that will happen with every type-parametrized class. for example `List`

```
scala> classOf[List[Int]]
res8: Class[List[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.List

scala> val l = List[Int](1, 2, 3, 4)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> l.getClass
res9: Class[_ <: List[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
```

Now coming back to your question, I think you just need to register `DenseVector` with `kryo`.

After that `kryo` should be able to deal with any `DenseVector[A]`, as long as that `A` is also registered with `kryo.`

Comment: The problem isn't type erasure with generics - that's happening too but kryo can handle it. It's specialized classes. http://www.scala-notes.org/2011/04/specializing-for-primitive-types/

Comment: What I am trying to hint at here is that you can do it the same way as you will for a `List`.

Comment: You mean like this: kryo.register(classOf[breeze.linalg.DenseVector[_]])
Unfortunetely that doesn't work as you're registering the type-erased DenseVector known at compile time, not the dynamically created specialization known at runtime. Kryo obviously throws as you haven't registered the specialized class. I've noticed that tuples are also specialized and are handled by twitter.chill's ScalaTupleSerialization.